# Control theory - feedback control of a damped oscillator to stabilise velocity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, matrix-equations, control-theory, linear-control

I am looking at applying some simple control theory to a damped oscillator.

If I have the following dynamics

\begin{equation}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \dot{x}\\
    \ddot{x} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 \\
    -\omega^2 & -\Gamma
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    x\\
    \dot{x} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
+
  \begin{bmatrix}
    0\\
    \dfrac{1}{m} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  u
\end{equation}

Such that my $A$ matrix is $\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 \\
    -\omega^2 & -\Gamma
  \end{bmatrix}$ and by B matrix is $  \begin{bmatrix}
    0\\
    \dfrac{1}{m} \\
  \end{bmatrix}$ and my control is $u$, an external force on the oscillator.

I can calculate the controllability matrix

\begin{equation}
  \mathcal{C} =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & \dfrac{1}{m} \\
    \dfrac{1}{m} & -\dfrac{\Gamma}{m} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  \label{controllability_matrix}
\end{equation}

which has rank 2. This means the controllability matrix has full column rank, this means, as I understand it, that this system is controllable. This means that we can arbitrarily place the
eigenvalues (also sometimes called poles) of the system dynamics by tuning $\mathbf{K}$ in $u =
-\mathbf{K}\vec{x}$ because the system dyamics becomes $\dot{\vec{x}} = (\mathbf{A} -
\mathbf{B}\mathbf{K})\vec{x}$. This also means we have reachability, meaning we can drive the system
to any state, the reachable set of states $R_t = \left\{ \xi ~\epsilon ~\mathbb{R}^n \right\}$.

If I then plug in $u = -K\vec{x}$ where I change $\vec{x}$ to $\vec{x}-\vec{x_t}$ where $\vec{x_t}$ is my target state I want to set the system to be driven towards.

\begin{equation}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \dot{x}\\
    \ddot{x} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 \\
    -\omega^2 & -\Gamma
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    x\\
    \dot{x} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  -
  \begin{bmatrix}
    0\\
    \dfrac{1}{m} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    K_0 & K_1 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    x - x_t \\
    \dot{x} - \dot{x}_t \\
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
which results in

\begin{equation}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \dot{x}\\
    \ddot{x} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 \\
    -\omega^2 & -\Gamma
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    x\\
    \dot{x} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  -
  \begin{bmatrix}
    0\\
    \dfrac{1}{m}K_0(x-x_t) + \dfrac{1}{m}K_1(\dot{x}-\dot{x}_t) \\
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

However when I put in some values for $\omega$, $\Gamma$ and $m$ and calculate the K matrix by setting the eigenvalues to be $n\times eig(A)$ [where n>1, the larger n is than 1 the more aggressive the feedback, I've used values like 1.5, 2, 3 ... etc ](this was just an initial guess - I wasn't sure where to place the eigenvalues to start - other than that they want to have a negative real value for stability and the more negative they are the more aggressive the feedback) by using `K = place(A, B, eigs(A)*n)` in matlab then I get a K matrix where $K_1$ is 0, and therefore I cannot control $\dot{x}$, why is this and how can I control $\dot{x}$?

I've been able to simulate this the see that it can control $x$.

Also, is it possible to set the system to be driven to any state by this control? It doesn't make sense that the system could be prepared in a state such as $x = 5cm$, $\dot{x} = 5m/s$ stably for example, as the positive velocity means it won't stay at $x = 5cm$. How can I calculate what states are reachable and stable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two equations in your system, $\frac{d}{dt}x=\dot x$ and 
$\frac{d}{dt}\dot x=-\omega^2x-\Gamma \dot x+u/m$. The control can only affect the second equation, the first one, whether we like it or not, is satisfied anyway. It means that it is impossible to stabilize the "solution" $x=5$, $\dot x= 5$: it is not a solution of the system. It violates the system's dynamics.

The only possible solutions are
$$\tag{1}
x=x_t(t),\quad \dot x= \dot x_t(t).
$$
In particular, if $x_t(t)=const$, then $\dot x_t$ must be zero. Any solution of the form (1) can be stabilized. But there is one point.

Suppose we want to stabilize the trajectory (1). Introduce the error
$$
e(t)= x(t)-x_t(t),\quad \dot e= \dot x(t)-\dot x_t(t).
$$
The error dynamics is 
$$
\frac{d}{dt}e= \dot e,
$$
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\dot e=\ddot x(t)-\ddot x_t(t)=
-\omega^2x-\Gamma \dot x+u/m-\ddot x_t(t)
$$
$$
=-\omega^2(e+x_t(t))-\Gamma (\dot e+\dot x_t(t))+u/m-\ddot x_t(t)
$$
$$
=-\omega^2 e-\Gamma \dot e+u/m-\ddot x_t(t)
-\omega^2 x_t(t)-\Gamma \dot x_t(t)
$$
Please notice the terms $-\ddot x_t(t)-\omega^2 x_t(t)-\Gamma \dot x_t(t)$. They do mean that if $x_t(t)$ is not a solution of the uncontrolled system (in other words, $\ddot x_t(t)\not\equiv -\omega^2 x_t(t)-\Gamma \dot x_t(t)$), then the control $u=-Ke$ does not, in general, stabilize it. The correct stabilizing control is
$$
u=m\left(
(\omega^2-c_0)e+(\Gamma-c_1)\dot e+\ddot x_t(t)+\omega^2 x_t(t)+\Gamma \dot x_t(t)
\right),
$$
where $c_0$, $c_1$ are some positive constants, or
$$
u=-Ke+m(\ddot x_t(t)+\omega^2 x_t(t)+\Gamma \dot x_t(t)),
$$
$$
K=-\left(m(\omega^2-c_0),m(\Gamma-c_1)\right).
$$

Comment: I've just had the time to work through this and it makes sense to me now, that you have to do this such that $\dfrac{d\dot{e}}{dt} = 0$ when $e =0$ and $\dot{e} = 0$ which means the system stable at $x = x_t$ and $\dot{x} = \dot{x}_t$ (although in practise for $x = x_t$ to be stable $\dot{x}_t$ must be 0 and for $\dot{x} = \dot{x}_t$ to be stable $x$ cannot be constant). How do I calculate the values of $c_0$ and $c_1$ to use for this control?

Comment: @SomeRandomPhysicist  $c_0$ and $c_1$ are the coefficients of the closed-loop error system $\ddot e+c_1\dot e+c_0 e=0$. This system is asymptotically stable iff $c_0>0$ and $c_1>0$.

Answer (score 1):

You must have failed in your code

```
>> A=[0 1;-rand(1) -rand(1)];
>> B=[0;rand(1)];
>> K = place(A,B,3*eig(A))

K =

   51.3265   14.2659
```

Controllability does not require that you stay at the state, only that you can reach it.

Comment: The problem appears to be that Gamma is very low relative to the frequency such that A effectively becomes A=[0 1;-rand(1) 0].

Comment: Is there a way around this other than using a lower frequency?

Comment: Ahh, nevermind, I found my mistake. I was just looking at the value of K in the command window, but when I inspected the matrix it had a small non-zero component for $K_1$

Comment: It appears the value is so low that it cannot exert any control. When I simulate the motion it is not moving the state to the velocity I target.

Comment: Hence badly scaled units in the model then I would say.

Comment: The units are physical, measured from an experimental oscillator which experiences very low damping.

Comment: I have frequencies of 70KHz - i.e. $\omega = 70e3\times2\pi$ and $\Gamma = 3000$, both of these parameters are in radians per second.

Comment: Being physical does not mean good. I should not measure the amount of Watts I need when working on an atomic level, as floating-point numerics will kill all computations at that level.

Comment: However, it feels like you perhaps have a poor control structure. If you want to control velocity, and use simple state-feedback, you will have steady-state error if you only feedback the error (for constant velocity, should $u$ be zero?...)

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Both on the floating point numerics front and the control structure point. I can edit the simulation to attempt to avoid the numerical issues. What would be a better control structure to have for controlling velocity in this kind of system? I've only spent a small amount of time learning the basics of control theory so far.

Comment: You typically use $u = u^* - K(x-x^*)$ where $u^*$ is the steady-state control related to the steady-state $x^*$, i.e. the solution to $0 = Ax^*+Bu^*$ (using standard state-space notation so $x$ is the state-vector)

Comment: and perhaps I should say: If you intend to control velocity, you should remove the position state. It should have no relevance for the problem (how I apply the throttle on my car when accelerating, is completely independent of where I am)

Comment: I see, and for this particular system I can not control position and velocity at the same time?

Comment: You never can, for obvious reasons which you brought up already in the question

Comment: Good, that makes sense, thanks.